# Converting Generics from Java to Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

I am trying to port some code from Java to Kotlin and came across a line in Java as

```
CsrfConfigurer<HttpSecurity> csrfConfigurer = http.getConfigurer(CsrfConfigurer.class);
```

The method is from [this class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java) line 250

But when I translated it to Kotlin language

```
val csrfConfigurer: CsrfConfigurer<HttpSecurity> = http.getConfigurer(CsrfConfigurer::class.java)
```

I get an error like [image]

Is this related to generics? How do I correct it?

Comment: Is there a sample gist somewhere showing the rest of code?

Comment: Just wants to call a java method.I have updated the question with link. Is that be fine?

Comment: Can you try this once?

```
val csrfConfigurer: CsrfConfigurer<HttpSecurity> = http.getConfigurer<CsrfConfigurer<HttpSecurity>>(CsrfConfigurer::class.java)
```

Comment: Thats what exactly I tried and got the error

Comment: Can you include the source for the http.configure method please or if you don't have access to it then at least the method reference for it it including the return type.

Comment: @KeithKirk Its a spring security class and reference in question and method is in line number 250

Comment: @JibinTJ can you include how `http` is initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Able to get this working with an explicit cast from the java class type to the class parameter type:

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    val csrfConfigurer: CsrfConfigurer<HttpSecurity> = http.getConfigurer(CsrfConfigurer::class.java as Class<CsrfConfigurer<HttpSecurity>>)
}
```